# 'npm install bcrypt' fails on Ubuntu 17.04 64 bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, bcrypt

I am trying to install bcrypt as a node dependency:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

**My environment:**

- Ubuntu 17.04, 64 bit
- node v6.11.0
- npm v4.2.0

I have followed the instructions for Ubuntu:

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#ubuntu-and-derivatives---elementary-linux-mint-etc

The installation seems to hang on the node-pre-gyp build.

**Stack trace:**

```
$ npm install bcrypt

    bcrypt@1.0.2 install /XXXXXX/node_modules/bcrypt
    node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

module.js:472
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/stream'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. (/XXXXXXXX/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:28:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-19-generic
npm ERR! argv "/XXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node" "/XXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.2 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Interestingly, I can install node-pre-gyp with npm, but node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build still fails.

Any advice?

Comment: You should try AskUbuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the GitHub issue thread:
https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/514

The g++ compiler was needed:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential g++

Answer (score 2):

use `bcrypt-nodejs` module instead of `bcrypt`

```
`npm install bcrypt-nodejs`
```

then

```
 var bcrypt  = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
```